# Reading in a full line from .txt file and storing specific information into different strings

Tags: c

So my .txt file looks like this:

```
Firstname MiddleName Lastname
Streetnumber streetname city state zipcode
```

I can use `fgets()` to read in each line easily; however I need to store each bit of information into its own char array.

Using `fscanf("%s%s%s", %(ptr->name.firstname), %(ptr->name.middlename, %(ptr->name.lastname))`

I can easily do this. However the problem I run into is when the information has a space in between. For example of someone entered the address info:

1223 West Minster London CA 12332

Using `fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s%s%s", &(ptr->streetno), &(ptr->streetname), &(ptr->city), &(ptr->state), &(ptr->zip)`

The stored values would be:

```
streetno: 1222, streetname: West, city: Minster, state: London, zip: CA.
```

`streetname` needs to be 'West Minster' but `fscanf("%s")` reads till a whitespace.

Comment: In that case, you have ambiguity and it would be best to switch the separator, maybe a `|`. Either that, or assume the state is only one word.

Comment: May be I am thinking too much here. How about reading from last and pickup zip and state and for city store list of cities in an array or text file and match it and left over should be street name and st. # which is integer.

Comment: Street names and city names both can be single words or multiple words.  With no punctuation to guide you, you have to do heuristic analysis of the words entered to deduce what was intended.  For example, you can assume that the last word is the zip code (and is all digits, or digits plus dash for zip+4), that the state is a two-letter abbreviation (rather than written out as New Mexico, etc), and then work backwards to deduce the city name and hence the street name.  In your example, there is nothing to tell you whether it is 1222 West, Minster London, CA or 1222 West Minster, London, CA.

Comment: Except in most other countries like Canada with zip codes that look like A1B 2C3

Comment: The fields aren't tab-separated by any chance?  If not, and if you can't change the format, you're kind of screwed due to the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

If the all words are separated by spaces, then the address alone is not enough information.   Consider

> 123 Biddle Lane Fort Lauderdale FL 33301

How can a "dumb" algorithm know where the division between street and city occurs?  It can't.

But all is not lost.  If all addresses are US, you have a way forward. You can obtain a [free database](http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/) that allows mapping zip codes to city names.  This can solve the ambiguity problem in many cases.  The algorithm would be something like:

1. Separate the line into words.  Say there are N of them.
2. Assume the last is zip code.
3. Look up the zip in database to obtain a state and primary city.
4. Verify N-1'th word is state that matches zip.
5. If primary city from database has M words, assume words N-3-M to N-2 are the city name.
6. Assume the words preceeding the city name are the street address.